# Value returns zero after one operation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, stocks

```
from numpy import std
import csv

data = []
with open('Data.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for column in zip(*reader):
        data.append(column)
dates = list(reversed(open('Dates.csv').read().split('\n')))
stock_value = [int(x) for x in open('stock_value.csv').read().split(',')]
companies = open('companies.csv').read().split(',')
stock_change = {}
with open('Data.csv') as file:
    reader = list(csv.reader(file))
    for i, j in enumerate(dates):
        stock_change[j] = map(float, reader[i])
company_value = dict(zip(companies, stock_value))


def change(invested, date):
    """Will return the change of invested stocks at the given date."""
    sum_product = sum([value[0] * value[1] * data for value, data
                  in zip(invested, stock_change[date])])
    _sum = sum([value[0] * value[1] for value in invested])
    return sum_product / _sum


def total_change(invested):
    """Will return the total change associated with an investment."""
    total_changes = []
    for date in dates:
        total_changes.append(change(list(zip(stock_value, invested)), date))
    return total_changes


def volatility(invested):
    """Will return the std deviation from the total_change of the invested."""
    return std(total_change(invested), ddof=1)


def tuner(invested):
    """Will return a weight list."""
    weights = []
    for i in range(465):
        temp = invested[:]
        temp1 = temp[:]
        print(stock_value)
        while True:
            temp[i] = temp[i] + 1
            if volatility(temp) < volatility(temp1):
                temp1 = temp[:]
            else:
                temp[i] = temp[i] - 1
                break
        weights.append(temp[i])
    return weights

invested = [0] * 465
invested[0] = 1
print(tuner(invested))
```

The Data.csv file contains 881 line with data like this:

```
1.7529880478,2.8552887735,2.2606138577,1.7495626093,0.9274873524,0.6702840728,0.2543720191,2.1072796935,2.2385449458,2.2860610965,0.2590673575,...
```

where each line corresponds to a date.
companies.csv is a file that contains 465 entries split by a comma with all the names of the companies and stock_value.csv contains 465 entries split by a comma where each entry is a value for the stock of the company  that is at the same index as it.

In the tuner function after I print volatility of temp, volatility of `temp1 = 0` and then in the next loop volatility of `temp = 0` and so is the volatility of `temp1`. Does anyone know why my values are becoming zero?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Sorry, I fixed it now.

Comment: Also, sorry, there are no dates in the example. And I believe the stock_change, and stock_value are also not included. It's hard to fix an example without all the details.

If this is too much, create an MVCE:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Is that enough detail or do I need more?

Comment: You might want to check your `change` and `total_change` functions. Honestly, I have a suspicion you're appending a single value to `total_change` and so your standard deviation will always be 0.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I would have gotten an error if the list only contained 1 item.

Comment: No, your list has many items: they are all the same though. `np.std(np.zeros(52)) == 0.0`, `np.std(np.ones(52)) == 0.0` for example.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh That's my problem. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: The easiest way would be a pdb debugger. Inside change, on the first line, put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and follow what each line does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wait. I know. Sorry, I just looked carefully at the code.

You have this (I changed it to make it a bit more legible):

```
def change(vs):
    product = sum([v[0] * v[1] * d for v, d in zip(vs, ds)])
    sums = sum([v[0] * v[1] for v in vs])
    return product / sums
```

Now, using basic math, we get that:

```
(v1 * v2 * d) / (v1 * v2)
(v1 * v2) * d / (v1 * v2)
d
```

So, this equation will always be equal to:

```
def change(vs):
    return sum(ds)
```

If you notice, your output does not depend on your input, so it is an independent variable, and therefore return a constant value, zeroing out all your values.

This is slightly oversimplified, since you do pass the date, which then grabs the stock change. But since the same array of dates is passed, you will get a constant array of values returned from `total_change`.